# Camel routes behave differently when embedded inside another application

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am new to Apache Camel so bear with me. I am trying to integrate simple camel routes shown below inside my messaging application that reads a message from ActiveMQ server, processes it, and sends it back to the sever. The problem is, when the routes below are executed as standalone camel application, they work fine (as expected). But when embedded in my application, they behave differently. First of all, all routes start when camel context is started even though some routes are not supposed to start automatically. Secondly, the startRoute and stopRoute methods of camel context do not get invoked. In my pom file I only have activemq-camel 5.6.0 dependency.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addComponent("activemq", ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("tcp://127.0.0.1:61616"));
    try {
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("activemq:queue:oldEvents")
                .routeId("sn")
                .process(new AddSequenceNumber())
                .to("activemq:queue:queue-P1-in");

                from("activemq:queue:queue-P1-in")
                .routeId("order")
                .resequence(header("seqnum"))
                .process(new Untapped())
                .stream(new StreamResequencerConfig(5000, 5000L))
                .to("activemq:queue:newEvents");

                from("activemq:queue:queue-P1-in")
                .routeId("tapOrder")
                .noAutoStartup()
                .wireTap("direct:tapped-messages")
                .resequence(header("seqnum"))
                .stream(new StreamResequencerConfig(5000, 5000L))
                .to("activemq:queue:newEvents");

                from("direct:tapped-messages")
                .routeId("checker")
                .noAutoStartup()
                .process(new SourceEventsChecker());    
            }               
        });
        context.start();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        context.stopRoute("order");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        context.startRoute("checker");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        context.startRoute("tapOrder");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where am I getting wrong? I am missing anything?

Inside my application, the routes are implemented in 'getCamelContext' method that returns camel context. Then, from another class I call the method and use the context to stop and start routes dynamically as shown below.

```
CamelContext context = MessageHandler.getCamelContext();
    try {
        context.stopRoute("order");
        context.startRoute("checker");
        context.startRoute("tap");
    } catch (Exception e`enter code here`) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: "But when embedded in my application..." _How_ are they embedded?

Comment: I have edited my question above. Thaks

Answer (score 0):

If you start your application with that `main` class you shown above in the code, then beware about the `start` method is a non-blocking call. Read more on the Camel website about how to run Camel standalone in a more better way.

- http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

eg use the `Main` class from Apache Camel and use its `run` method to keep the JVM running.

Comment: I have tried to use camel's Main class, even read chapter 13 of camel in action as suggested by the above link. But, the problem still exist. The only call that works is main.start(), because I can see the routes being executed when the method is being called. One thing I have noticed is that, if I call main.stop() in same scope (e.g if block) as the main.start(), it also works but if I move main.stop() into else if block of the same if statement, it doesn't work. Keep in mind that main is a global variable.

Comment: Just to add from above comment, main.getCamelContexts().forEach(context -> {System.out.println(context.getRoutes().size());
}); returns 0 even though I can see my routes being executed.